# typeahead no results no console error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

bootstrap-ui typeahead shows no results.

controller

```
    .controller('FakturaAddCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.selected = undefined;
        $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Wyoming'];
});
```

view

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> State</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
                        </div>
```

used example on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

when i run i just got the input field, but no drop down data (typeahead function dosen't run?)

also got no console errors

Comment: Make sure you also include templates for typeahead.

Comment: @dfsq thats included in 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js' ?

Comment: It should be `uib-typeahead` not `bs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to ***ui-bootstrap*** but using the directive from ***angularStrap***, which is another module.

Replace:

```
bs-options="state for state in states"  bs-typeahead
```

with:

**ui-bootstrap >= 0.14 :**

```
uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter: $viewValue"
```

**ui-bootstrap < 0.14 :**

```
typeahead="state for state in states | filter: $viewValue"
```

Comment: changed to '  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"> '   but gives still no result and no console error

Comment: Did you added `ui.bootstrap` in the module dependencies array?

Comment: They went through a name change in 0.14. If you're under that version, remove the `uib-` prefix in the directive name. Or upgrade to 0.14+.

Comment: yes it was, upgrading both ui.bootstrap and angular did the job thx ! :D

Comment: you can add this answer if you want

Comment: Added syntax for versions < 0.14 in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me ---

```
typeahead="state for state in states | filter: $viewValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to check the module, whether you added `ui.bootstrap` or not

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [...., 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

For me, I missed it and waste my 2 hours.